# PHP program create installable package

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I have the following PHP script, and I'd like to create a package that people can install easy, something similar to this:

```
sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
```

Any ideas on how can I do this?

***/home/script.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting NAME service"
sudo -u root php -f /home/script.php &
```

***/home/script.php***

```
<?php

// The worker will execute every X seconds:
$seconds = 2;

// We work out the micro seconds ready to be used by the 'usleep' function.
$micro = $seconds * 1000000;

while(true){
 // This is the code you want to loop during the service...
 $myFile = "/home/filephp.txt";
 $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("Can't open file");
 $stringData = "File updated at: " . time(). "\n";
 fwrite($fh, $stringData);
 fclose($fh);

 // Now before we 'cycle' again, we'll sleep for a bit...
 usleep($micro);
}
```

***/etc/systemd/system/name.service***

```
[Unit]
Description=Crawler cache Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Restart=always
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved creating the following folder tree:

```
> package_name/
>> DEBIAN/
>>> control
>> usr/
>>> share/
>>>> package_name/
>>>>> script.sh
>>>>> script.php
>> etc/
>>> systemd/
>>>> system/
>>>>> name.service
```

In the "control" file you have to set some parameters, like the version number or dependencies.

```
Package: package_name
Version: 0.0.1
Section: base
Priority: optional
Architecture: all
Depends: php, php-curl
Maintainer: Marcos Aguayo <marcos@aguayo.es>
Description: Package description
```

After that you only have to type the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-deb --build package_name/
```

When you have the .deb package, if you want to install it you can use this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb # --> Install .deb
systemctl start package_name  # --> Start the service
```